# Basic txt File being created but not written to

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files

Im a beginner in C# and was just working on something to practice with, anyways, I can get this to write to a txt file in the Bin folder of the project using just StreamWriter and File.CreateText, but when I try to add a path and Append it I get a File but nothing written to it.

Im just using WinFormApp

```
try
{
    string mypath = @"C:\Temp\Rocket League Tracker.txt";

    StreamWriter RocketLeagueTrackerFile;

    RocketLeagueTrackerFile = File.CreateText(mypath);
    RocketLeagueTrackerFile.WriteLine("Rocket League Tracking");

    File.AppendAllText(mypath, MyGameResult + Environment.NewLine);

    RocketLeagueTrackerFile.Close();
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Remove the try/catch and probably you will see the problem

Comment: instead of catch, add catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); } to see the problem. put the message here for more help. it is not clear what is `MyGameResult` in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call *File.CreateText* you are acquiring a lock on that file.
The following call to *File.AppendAllText* doesn't use the returned StreamWriter from File.CreateText but it tries again to acquire a lock on the same file.
This leads to an exception (IOException) but you can't see it because you have added an empty try/catch.

Never use empty try/catch without reason because you hide exceptional situations and your program could crash without an explanation at your user desktop.
Or you loose hours searching a misterious bug and need to call SO (like here).

If you really need to show a message to your user then

```
.....
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unexpected Error:" + ex.Message);
    // Rethrow the exception to upper layers....
    throw; 
}
```

Said that, you don't need the File.CreateText because File.AppendAllText according to MSDN

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method **creates a
>   file**, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

```
string mypath = @"C:\Temp\Rocket League Tracker.txt";
string title = "Rocket League Tracking";
File.AppendAllText(mypath, title + Environment.NewLine + 
                           MyGameResult + Environment.NewLine);
```

Or replace File.AppendAllText with File.WriteAllText if you need to always overwrite a previous file with that name.

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I  sincerely appreciate it. I had noticed I was getting the exception and was going to follow up with it, but you touched on it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use using statement for this. `File.CreateText` is locking file.

```
using(RocketLeagueTrackerFile = File.CreateText(mypath))
{            
     RocketLeagueTrackerFile.WriteLine("Rocket League Tracking");
}

File.AppendAllText(mypath, MyGameResult + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
File.WriteAllText(mypath ,"Rocket League Tracking");
```